# Salvar saida script query Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Olá a todos não sou desenvolvedor mas estou ajudando em uma integração entre sistemas o sistema principal de controle de vendas utiliza um BD em Postgres instalado em Linux criei um script abaixo a partir de uma query repassado pelo DEV para encontrar um saldo de estoque de produtos para o segundo sistema importar esse estoque em um arquivo .txt, o mesmo funciona e imprime em tela o resultado a partir do "raise notice" quando o executo com psql, porém não encontro uma forma de exportar isso para um TXT quando gravo a saída grava somente a chamada do DO

```
.sql

do $$  

declare  

        entra decimal;
        saida decimal;
        saldo decimal;

begin   

        entra := 
    SUM(quantid)
    FROM    lancamento
    WHERE   lancamento.data > '2023-01-01'
    AND lancamento.loja = 2673456
    AND lancamento.prod = 8032658
    AND lancamento.via = 'E'; 


        saida := 
    SUM(quantidade)
    FROM    lancamento
    WHERE   lancamento.data > '2023-01-01'
    AND lancamento.loja = 2673456
    AND lancamento.prod = 8032658
    AND lancamento.via = 'V'; 

        saldo := entra - saida;

        raise notice 'Saldo: % .', saldo;
        
end $$;

.sql
```

uso psql -f query.sql > result.txt

Answer (score -3):

Eu uso no EXCEPTION, faço o EXECUTE chamar o Copy para gerar o arquivo

```
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN
BEGIN        
    EXECUTE 'COPY ( select '||quote_literal(TG_TABLE_NAME)||' as lg_tabela, '||quote_literal(TG_OP)||' as lg_acao) TO '||quote_literal('C:\logs\arquivo'||id||'.csv')||' DELIMITER '||quote_literal(',')||' CSV HEADER';
    
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```